# MYSQL view not ordering as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of cocktail recipes and other stuff.  I have another table that shows the recipes that have been liked. I want to make a view of the mentioned recipes in the last day, and if that result is <1000, fill in the remaining 1000 with random recipes NOT on the FEED table.

Example

**Feed**: Recipe 1 liked today (1 min ago) (cocktail), Recipe 2 liked yesterday (not cocktail), recipe 3 liked today (1 hour ago)(cocktail), recipe 4 liked today (3 minutes ago) (not cocktail).

**Recipe table**:
self explanatory

**Category table:**

```
recipe 1, cocktail
recipe 2, juice
recipe 3, cocktail
recipe 4 juice
recipe 3333 cocktail
recipe 4444 cocktail
recipe nnnn cocktail
```

My **View** needs to show:

Recipe 1, recipe 4,Recipe 3 (liked in most recent order). THEN to fill the rest of the 1000, get random from the recipe table: Recipe 4444, recipe 3333, recipe nnnn.

**Final result**: Recipe 1, recipe 4,Recipe 3, Recipe 4444, recipe 3333, recipe nnnn

The code below attempts to do this, but the order is wrong (the top doesn't have recipe 1, 4, 3 in that order. They are mixed around...

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `XXXX` 
    SQL XXXX
VIEW `cocktails` AS
    (select 
        `r`.`name` AS `name`,
        `r`.`myId` AS `myId`
    from
        ((`recipe` `r`
        join `feed` `f` ON ((`r`.`myId` = `f`.`recipe_id`)))
        join `category` `c` ON ((`r`.`myId` = `c`.`recipe_id`)))
    where
        (`c`.`name` like '%cocktails%')
    group by `r`.`name`
    order by (max(`f`.`timeStamp`) >= (now() - interval 1 day)) desc , (`r`.`myId` is not null) desc)

    union 

    (select 
        `r`.`name` AS `name`,
        `r`.`myId` AS `myId`
    from
        ((`recipe` `r`
        join `category` `c` ON (`r`.`myId` = `c`.`recipe_id`)))
    where
        (`c`.`name` like '%cocktails%')

    )
    limit 0,1000
```

Comment: The `UNION` does not provide any ordering guarantees - the results are *just a set* until materialized. You must order immediately before the materialization (i.e. final select).

Comment: I would use two queries. Otherwise you can carry along a discriminating value (and possibly row order) to apply a final sort (*outside* the UNION) based on the values. I'm not sure about MySQL, but SQL Server doesn't guarantee the order of ORDER BY in a VIEW at all (excluding TOP hacks).

Comment: Also revisit the schema/query - the ORDER BY seems overly complex (unable to use indexes?) and the GROUP BY does not cover the id.

Comment: why are you grouping? (`group by r.name`) you don't use any aggregate...

Comment: You don't need to quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Comment: Sql workbench adds them for me for some reason. I normally don't use them (please let me know if You know how to disable them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use an `order by` in a view in MySQL.  However, I think you can solve your problem by combining the queries.  Do a `left outer join` to the `feeds` table.  Then, order the results by the presence of the feeds:

```
CREATE VIEW cocktails AS
    select r.name, r.myId
    from recipe r join
         category c
         ON r.myId = c.recipe_id left outer join
         feed f
         ON r.myId = f.recipe_id
    where c.name like '%cocktails%'
    group by r.name
    order by (f.recipe_id is not null) desc,
             max(f.timestamp) >= (now() - interval 1 day) desc,
             r.myId is not null desc
    limit 0,1000;
```

I also got rid of the back quotes -- they make the code quite hard to read.

Comment: Do you really write your joins like that, on the same line as the previous join's predicate?

Comment: @siride . . . Absolutely.  This is the format I always use.  It highlights what I think is important.  Visually, I can easily spot the tables (which line up vertically) and the conditions (which are just below the tables).  And, it separates the `from` clause from the other SQL clauses.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. On the note of formatting, do you have any links that show commonly used formatting for calls? I keep wanting to split up the queries like I would code, but it's not the same

Comment: There are different formatting styles.  Mine is documented in my book "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel."

Comment: I understand having the tables lined up and the conditions on the next line (I do the same), but putting the join type way in right field seems...odd.